# Casting a FormArray to an array angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a FormArray of FormGroups, i want to iterate over the FormArray and detect which FormGroups are valid. However i am unable to do so as i am unable to iterate over a FormArray as it is not of type Array or string. My logic was to somehow cast the FormArray into an Array if possible. However i do not know the syntax in typescript for this.

```html
 this.applicationFormArray = new FormArray([
            this.selectAppFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            }),
            this.generalAppFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            }),
            this.fileModeFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            }),
            this.accessListFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            }),
        ]);
```

```html
checkValidity() {
        var foo = this.applicationFormArray as Array<>;
        for(var element of this.applicationFormArray){
            if(element.valid) {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Each control inherited from abstract form control, so control has valid property.please check out this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` together with the `length` of `FromArray` and the `at` method:

```
let array = new Array(this.applicationFormArray.length)
    .map((v, index) => this.applicationFormArray.at(index) as FormGroup);
```

Although the for version is not too bad either:

```
for (let i =0;i< this.applicationFormArray.length;i++) {
    const element = this.applicationFormArray.at(i);
    if (element.valid) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: if the form array was a formgroup of formgroups how would you loop through that?

Comment: You want to get the values on all levels ? You would need to do something recursive

Comment: instead of it being a formarray i am thinking of changing it to a formgroup. But i cannot loop through that in the same way. My other question is can you assign a string value to the form group to reference it by the name.

Comment: @ashleyg `FormGroup` has a `controls` property, you can iterate over the properties of that `for (let c of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(applicationFormArray.controls)) applicationFormArray.controls[c];`

Comment: perfect! this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: map doesn't work on empty array rather it calls the callback on each array item, so first `fill` the array and then use `map`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a FormArray to a regular Array with the FormArray's value property. This is what worked for me. Using the value property on a FormGroup returns an object literal and on a FormArray it returns an array.

```
let newArr = this.applicationFormArray.value
newArr.map(...)
```

In your example it would look like this:

```
var foo = this.applicationFormArray.value;
for(var element of foo){
   if(element.valid) {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution could be to use a filter and get only the valid forms.

`const myValidForms = formArray.controls.filter(myForm => myForm.valid);`

Answer (score -3):

Try using foreach instead of

```
this.applicationFormArray.forEach(element => {
    if(element.valid) {
        //do something
    }    
});
```

Comment: You still have the same problem. The problem is how to convert the `FormArray` to an `Array`. If you're able to do that, then either `for` or `forEach` would work.